# shiny leaflet data not found

Tags: r, leaflet

For a shiny app that will render a leaflet map I am using the "Crime" dataset found in the 'ggmap' package.  There are two Inputs am trying to implement. One is the 'offense', the other is the 'month' variables. These variables are available as drop down from shiny. The objective is to filter and display by the combination of the offense type and month. Ex. robbery in April for example...

When excuted, I get the *`Point data not found;`* error.

Here is a code construct to extract data.

```
fData <- reactive({
  data <- hustonCrime

           if (input$offenseFilter != "All"){
                  data <- subset(hustonCrime, offense %in% input$offenseFilter) 
                  }
           if (input$monthFilter != "All"){
                   data <- subset(hustonCrime, month %in% input$monthFilter) 
                 }
   })
```

Comment: Might just be an issue of not returning your data. Try adding `return(data)` at the end of that code. Also, as an aside, I don't think your code is currently filtering the way you intend it to.

Comment: Thanks brittenb! 'return(data)' fixed one of the issue. The app can now  filter per variable on the map, but not in combination I intended. Any suggestion on filtering with the effect I intended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix the bad filtering situation you have to switch your code to the following:

```
fData <- reactive({
  data <- hustonCrime
  if (input$offenseFilter != "All") {
    data <- subset(data, offense %in% input$offenseFilter)
  }
  if (input$monthFilter != "All") {
    data <- subset(data, month %in% input$monthFilter)
  }
  return(data)
})
```

The problem in your code is that you kept resetting `data` to be a subset of `hustonCrime`, when in reality, you wanted to keep subsetting `data`.

#### Edit

As indicated in the comments, this code cumulatively filters the data as opposed to the code in the original question. To see this, let's walk through what happens with each code as inputs are changed in the Shiny app.

First, let's not change anything at all. Both inputs are set to "All".

**Original Code**:
Shiny loads the app and `fData` is created since it's a reactive element. Shiny steps into the reactive function and sets `data` equal to `hustonCrime`. It then checks `input$offenseFilter` and `input$monthFilter` and sees that they both equal "All" and it makes no changes to `data`. It then returns `data`.

**New Code**:
The exact same thing happens as in the Original Code.

Next, let's see what happens when the use changes `input$offenseFilter`.

**Original Code**:
Shiny recognizes that `input$offenseFilter` has changed and finds all reactive elements that depend on that variable. It finds `fData` and steps into the code. It sets `data` equal to `hustonCrime` and then checks if `input$offenseFilter` is equal to "All". It finds that it is not and it subsets `hustonCrime` such that `offense` is a value in the vector of elements in `input$offenseFilter`. It next checks if `input$monthFilter` is equal to "All" and finds that it is, so it makes no changes. The function returns `data`, which is set to the filtered `hustonCrime`.

**New Code**:
Shiny recognizes that `input$offenseFilter` has changed and finds all reactive elements that depend on that variable. It finds `fData` and steps into the code. It sets `data` equal to `hustonCrime` and then checks if `input$offenseFilter` is equal to "All". It finds that it is not and it subsets `data`, **NOT** `hustonCrime`, which will be important in the next step, and moves on. It acknowledges that `input$monthFilter` is equal to "All" and returns `data`, which is a subset of the original `data`.

Now, let's look at the last step where the user also choose a month filter.

**Original Code**:
Shiny steps into the `fData` reactive function and sets `data` equal to `hustonCrime`. It then overwrites `data` with the subset of `hustonCrime` where `offense` is in `input$offenseFilter`. Next, it sees that `input$monthFilter` does not equal "All" and it again *overwrites* `data` with a new subset of `hustonCrime` where `month` is in the vector of elements in `input$monthFilter`. Since `data` has just been overwritten with a subset of `hustonCrime` that only depended on `month`, it no longer includes the filter by `offense`.

**New Code**:
Shiny steps into the function, sets `data` equal to `hustonCrime` and then overwrites `data` with a subset of itself, not the `hustonCrime` data set. Next, it finds that `input$monthFilter` is not equal to "All" and again overwrites `data` with a subset of itself. This is important because prior to this step, `data` was filtered by `offense` while `hustonCrime` was not. Since `data` is already filtered by `offense`, filtering it by `month` now gives us the interaction we're looking for in the filtering.

In the end, the original code keeps overwriting data with subsets of the whole data set, when in reality we want to keep subsetting our working dataset to include all filters that have been selected.

Comment: As I mentioned above in my reply, adding 'retrun(data)' fixed one of the issues - the other is being able to filter in combination of offense and month ..

Comment: The above should have fixed your problem with filtering in combination. As I state in the answer, your code currently replaces `data` with a new subset of `hustonCrime` at each step, which will leave you with only one or the other from your filtered variables. I'll edit the question to walk you through this in detail.

Comment: Thanks again brittenb.  Objective is - to select offense = robbery and month = june - and display ONLY robberies in june. As it is I am seeing all offenses in june - even though offense on input is robbery.  I'm playing with dplyr filter function - but not there yet...

Comment: Did you change your code to match mine? Because based on what you're saying, it doesn't seem like you did. The code above did not only add `return(data)` to the code.